# Show that function doesn't have derivative at any point

Tags: complex-analysis

Complex function
$$
f(z) = \sqrt{|Re(z)Im(z)|}
$$
Doesn't have derivative at point $z_0 = 0$, because
$$
\lim_{z\;\rightarrow\;0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = \lim_{\rho\;\rightarrow\;0} \frac{\rho\sqrt{cos(\phi)sin(\phi)}}{\rho e^{i\phi}} = \frac{\sqrt{cos(\phi)sin(\phi)}}{e^{i\phi}}
$$
When I try to prove that $f(z)$ doesn't have derivative at any point, I am stuck on solving the limit.

I get the following

$$
\lim_{z\;\rightarrow\;z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = \lim_{z\;\rightarrow\;z_0} \frac{\sqrt{|Re(z)Im(z)|} - \sqrt{|Re(z_0)Im(z_0)|}}{z-z_0}
$$
I try using substitution
$$
z-z_0 = \rho e^{i\phi}
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{\rho\;\rightarrow\;0} \frac{\sqrt{|Re(\rho e^{i\phi}+z_0)Im(\rho e^{i\phi}+z_0)|} - \sqrt{|Re(z_0)Im(z_0)|}}{\rho e^{i\phi}}
$$

But I have no idea how to proceed further. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Cauchy-Riemann equations. If you write $f(x+yi)=u(x,y)+v(x,y)i$, with $u(x,y),v(x,y)\in\mathbb R$, then $u(x,u)=\sqrt{\lvert xy\rvert}$ and $v(x,y)=0$. But then$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(x,y)\\\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x,y)\end{array}\right.\iff\left\{\begin{array}{l}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x,y)=0\\\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}(x,y)=0\end{array}\right.\iff(x,y)=(0,0),$$but you have already proved that $f$ is *not* differentiable at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 2):

A basic fact about differentiation in the complex analytic sense is that C-R equations are necessary for differentiation. In this case C-R equation show that $\Re z =\Im z$ and $\Re z =-\Im z$ so the only we only have to consider the the point $z=0$.